# using regular expressions across multiple lines (DOTALL / MULTILINE)

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to read a .nk file, and I am trying to use regular expressions to search for specific items in the file.

Here's an example of 1 such item inside of this .nk file:

```
Viewer {
 inputs 2
 frame 1073
 viewerProcess "common"
 input_process false
 name Viewer1
 xpos -8403
 ypos -39859
}
```

I am currently playing around with this regular expression:

```
viewers = re.findall("(Viewer\s{.*})", TEXT, re.DOTALL)
```

The problem with this is that it fails to stop at the } symbol. So the regex returns every single line in the .nk file after "Viewer\s{"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Python to match [non-greedily](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (as little as possible):

```
viewers = re.findall("(Viewer\s{.*?})", TEXT, re.DOTALL)
#                                 ^
```

Otherwise, your pattern will capture everything from the first `Viewer\s{` to the last `}` in the file.

Comment: ah ha! This is prefect!

Answer (score 2):

iCodez has a good solution; another possible way would be to make it explicit that no braces may be part of the match by using a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
viewers = re.findall(r"(Viewer\s{[^{}]*})", TEXT, re.DOTALL)
```